# Pick a key from a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

go through a dictionary picking keys from it in a loop?

For example lets say I have the following dictionary: `{'hello':'world', 'hi':'there'}`. Is there a way to `for` loop through the dictionary and print `hello, hi`?

on a similar note is there a way to say `myDictionary.key[1]` and that will return `hi`?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys of a dict with a for loop:

```
>>> for key in yourdict:
>>>    print(key)
hi
hello
```

If you want them as a comma separated string you can use `', '.join`.

```
>>> print(', '.join(yourdict))
hi, hello
```

---

> on a similar note is there a way to say myDictionary.key[1](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and that will return hi

No. The keys in a dictionary are not in any particular order. The order that you see when you iterate over them may not be the same as the order you inserted them into the dictionary, and also the order could in theory change when you add or remove items.

if you need an ordered collection you might want to consider using another type such as a `list`, or an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: how do you say myDictionary.key(1)? what is the method call?

Comment: myDictionary.keys()[1] will do that, but as Mark noted, you cannot rely on the order

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.keys()` method:

```
for key in myDictionary.keys():
   print(key)
```

---

You can also use `.items()` to iterate through both at the same time:

```
for key, value in myDictionary.items():
   print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the dictionary name as a sequence produces all the keys:

```
>>> d={'hello':'world', 'hi':'there'}
>>> list(d)
['hi', 'hello']
```

so `list({'hello':'world', 'hi':'there'})[1]` produces element 1 of the list of keys.

This is of limited use, however, because dictionaries are unordered. And their order may be different than the order of insertion:

```
>>> d={'a': 'ahh', 'b': 'baa', 'c': 'coconut'}
>>> d
{'a': 'ahh', 'c': 'coconut', 'b': 'baa'}
```

You can do `sorted(list({'hello':'world', 'hi':'there'}))[1]` for the 1 element of a sorted list of the keys of your dict. That produces 'hi' in this case. Not the most readable or efficient though...

You should look at [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want a sorted order.

Or just sort into a list:

```
>>> d={'a': 'ahh', 'b': 'baa', 'c': 'coconut'}
>>> l=[(k,v) for k, v in d.items()]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l[1]
('b', 'baa')
>>> l[1][0]
'b'
```

You can reverse `(k,v)` to `(v,k)` if you want to sort by value instead of by key.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.iterkeys` in Python 2, `dict.keys` in Python 3.

```
d = { 'hello': 'world', 'hi': 'there' }
for key in d.iterkeys():
    print key
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a list of keys would meet your needs:

```
>>> d = { 'hello': 'world', 'hi': 'there' }
>>> keys = list(d)
>>> keys
['hi', 'hello']
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice(keys)
'hi'
```